# BEM - How to manage multiple nested class names

Tags: html, css, naming-conventions, bem

I have the following,

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="header__top">
        <div class="container">

            <ul class="top-nav"><!-- new name -->

                <li class="dropdown top-nav__profile">
                    <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown">Hi Mallinda!</a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
                        <li class="top-nav__saved"><a href="">Saved Searches</a></li>
                        <li class="top-nav__saved"><a href="">Saved Agents</a></li>
                        <li class="top-nav__saved"><a href="">Saved Listings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Email Preferences</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="top-nav__icon">
                    <a href=""><i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications"></i></a>
                </li>

                <li class="pull-right top-nav__icon">
                    <a href=""><i class="zmdi zmdi-facebook"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="pull-right top-nav__icon">
                    <a href=""><i class="zmdi zmdi-twitter"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="pull-right top-nav__icon">
                    <a href=""><i class="zmdi zmdi-google"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Since I have a lot of nested classes, I've decided to choose a new name 'top-nav' after certain level. Is it valid in BEM? or do I need to phrase block name 'header__' to every child element?

Answer (score 0):

You may put blocks inside other blocks or elements. It is absolutely valid.

Comment: I just waned to add - inner blocks should be self defined components. The main thing of BEM - is to think component way.